# Add box-shadow to bottom of div from middle

Tags: css, border, box-shadow

I've attached a preview of what I wanted. I honestly couldn't get the right words for it so I've got no luck searching how to do this.

[image: Some sort of card effect]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);`

Comment: @Blazemonger sorry, this isn't what I was trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pseudo element to create an oval shape and give it a box shadow. Play around with the `box-shadow` and `height` values to get exactly what you want.

```
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hkpy6eup/4/

Answer (score 0):

I just used displayed the image I provided to the bottom. Not sure if there's another way